# What does the "and" operator do in mips?

Tags: mips

Suppose there was an instruction that said and $t0, $t1, $t2 . $t1 holds the value 3 and $t2 holds the value 5. What would the instruction do and what would be in register $t0?

Comment: Almost certainly, bitwise AND.

Comment: _"What would the instruction do"_: See _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_. _"What would be in register $t0"_: Fire up Windows' `calc` in programmer mode, or do the calculation with pen and paper.

Comment: You need to do your research before you ask a question. This question is clearly a duplicate.